# mongodb: atomically remove first n elements of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to atomically remove the first n elements of an array field.

Right now, I use `model.find()`, then `doc.arrayField.slice(n)`, then `doc.save()`. But this loads the entire document in memory (bad if document is very large), and it would kill the atomicity.

Is there a way to achieve this atomically in MongoDB/Mongoose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$pop` to remove first element atomically. Or if you can specify which fields to remove you can use `$pull` to remove multiple items from an array. Otherwise you cannot remove first n elements from array in an atomic operation using mongodb.

```
db.yourCollection.update({}, {$pop: {arrayField: 1}}}) // will remove the first element from arrayField

db.yourCollection.update({}, {$pull: {arrayField: {foo: "bar"}}}}) // will remove all elements whose foo field equal to bar from arrayField.
```

Comment: Would this work? https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/slice/#update-array-using-slice-only

Comment: You want to remove the first n element, `slice` can be used to save the first n element. So in your case I don't think it will help you. But if you know the size of your array you might again use `slice` operator with `each` operator to keep the last n elements. For example db.yourCollection.update({}, {$pull: {arrayField: {$each:[], $slice: -5}}}}) // will keep the last 5 elements of the array

Comment: To remove the first element should use -1 and not 1.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB provides `$slice` operator for array updates. https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/slice/

You can use in Mongoose updateClause too.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of loading all arrayField data in memory, you can use [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/projection/slice/) to **project** docs with first n elements of arrayFields like this

```
model.find({}, {arrayField : {$slice: n}}) // n is first n elements
```

Now you can remove those n elements using

```
doc.arrayField.slice(n);
doc.save();
```

Comment: These are two operations. So it's not atomically.